# How to get the site collection search results page in Sharepoint 2010?

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

There's a "Site Collection Search Results Page" field which is used for configuring the search results page used for contextual searches (such as "This Site").  It can be found by doing the following:

1. Go to your SharePoint site collection
2. Select "Site Settings" from the "Site Actions" menu
3. Go to the "Site Collection Administration" section and select "Search Settings"
4. The field "Site Collection Search Results Page" will be listed on the bottom.

The default value is

```
/_layouts/osssearchresults.aspx
```

How can I retrieve and change this value through the SharePoint object model?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The setting is stored in:

```
site.RootWeb.AllProperties["SRCH_TRAGET_RESULTS_PAGE"]
```

If doesn't exist or is null then '/_layouts/osssearchresults.aspx' is used

The Search Center URL is in

```
site.RootWeb.AllProperties["SRCH_ENH_FTR_URL"]
```

And the drop down mode in

```
site.RootWeb.AllProperties["SRCH_SITE_DROPDOWN_MODE"]
```

Comment: This changes value of Site Collection Search Center (i.e. enables custom scopes). But I need to change the URL to layout itself.

Comment: Upps :-( gave the setting for 2007, where the page was hardcoded. Answer is now updated for 2010.

Comment: Remember to do site.RootWeb.Update() to have the changes actually go into effect.

Comment: And yes, it is spelt TRAGET in the property.

Comment: Also, be sure to wait 30 seconds to 1 minute after the Web.Update() because it seems to take a little while to take affect.  If you immediately try it and the setting is not applied, you could be tempted to start changing values and you may just need to be patient.

Comment: How did you figure this out? Is there documentation on these properties?

Comment: As far as I remember I looked at the code behind the Search Settings Page